# How can I add top (and bottom) padding to a pNiceMatrix?

Tags: matrices, nicematrix

I'm attempting to create a matrix where the basis I'm using appears to the top and left of the matrix, and based on online suggestions, I landed on using either the built-in `\bordermatrix` or the `blockarray` or `pNiceMatrix` environments from the `blkarray` and `nicematrix` packages respectively. I'm liking the formatting of `pNiceMatrix` the most so far, but there just isn't enough space between the top of the parentheses of the matrix and the entries of the first row. This would also be a problem on the bottom if I were using the bottom row. Here's my current code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-col, first-row]
                        & v_1 & \dots  & v_n & w_1 & \dots & w_m \\
    \Block{1-1}{v_1}    & 1   &        & 0   &     &       & \\
    \Block{1-1}{\vdots} &     & \ddots &     &     & A     & \\
    \Block{1-1}{v_n}    & 0   &        & 1   &     &       & \\
    \Block{1-1}{w_1}    &     &        &     &     &       & \\
    \Block{1-1}{\vdots} &     & 0      &     &     & 0     & \\
    \Block{1-1}{w_m}    &     &        &     &     &       & \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which gives the following result:

[image]

You may notice that I also had some issue horizontally centering the `\vdots` as well, and I'm not super happy with how clunky the solution for that was. The `\Vdots` provided in the package have too many dots for my liking.

Anyways, that `1` in the top left is right at or a little bit above the top of the parenthesis. All I want is a little bit of padding on the top to make that look nicer. I've combed through the `nicematrix` documentation and haven't found anything useful. There are plenty of options for horizontal padding (i.e. the `margin`
parameter), and there is `cell-space-top-limit`, but this adjusts the spacing for every row, not just the top. The only other solution I've seen suggested is to add a row to the top and just adjust the height manually, but I want to see if there's a non-hacky way to do it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a `\rule` to the top-left cell, for padding.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-col, first-row]
                        & v_1 & \dots  & v_n & w_1 & \dots & w_m \\
    \Block{1-1}{v_1}    & \rule{0pt}{3ex}1   &        & 0   &     &       & \\
    \Block{1-1}{\vdots} &     & \ddots &     &     & A     & \\
    \Block{1-1}{v_n}    & 0   &        & 1   &     &       & \\
    \Block{1-1}{w_1}    &     &        &     &     &       & \\
    \Block{1-1}{\vdots} &     & 0      &     &     & 0     & \\
    \Block{1-1}{w_m}    &     &        &     &     &       & \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One might also add a negative `\rule` to the bottom-left cell of the label vector:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-col, first-row]
                        & v_1 & \dots  & v_n & w_1 & \dots & w_m \\
    \Block{1-1}{v_1}    & \rule{0pt}{3ex}1   &        & 0   &     &       & \\
    \Block{1-1}{\vdots} &     & \ddots &     &     & A     & \\
    \Block{1-1}{v_n}    & 0   &        & 1   &     &       & \\
    \Block{1-1}{w_1}    &     &        &     &     &       & \\
    \Block{1-1}{\vdots} &     & 0      &     &     & 0     & \\
    \Block{1-1}{\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{0pt}w_m}    &     &        &     &     &       & \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]